# django User update_fields not showing up in signal

Tags: django, signals

i am using django signal to create a user profile automatically when the user is created ,
and it is work fine ,
but i want to check also if the user trying to update his "username or email or ..... etc ."
i am trying to check these values in signal , but always
the 'update_fields' value is None !

'as you can see in the block of code below '

```
# create profile automatically  when the user is created using (signal) ##
def create_profile(sender , **kwargs):
if kwargs['created']:
    Profile.objects.create(PRF_user=kwargs['instance'])

if kwargs['update_fields']:
    print ('some table are updated this is a test')

print('all kwargs')
print(kwargs)
print('end kwargs')

   #done create profile automatically  ##

post_save.connect(create_profile , sender=User)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOdGP.jpg)

```
outprint
all kwargs
{'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x00000000037D2780>,
'instance': <User: khder_admin@local.com>, 'created': False, 'update_fields': No
ne, 'raw': False, 'using': 'default'}
end kwargs
```

how can i tell django to populate 'update_fields' values and send it by signal to my function!? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting what [update_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) are for. They are used for limiting the scope of fields that should be updated, and also setting update_fields forces update query

If you want to know which fields are updated you should manually check old database instance fields and fields to be set. Django does not have recollection of fields that have been updated

Comment: thanks for clear explanation